# Tableau and modified Sankey diagram

Tags: tableau-api, sankey-diagram

I have been trying to recreate a modified Sankey based on Adam's work with the American Whiskey Viz and Beatles Analysis Viz that are found here:

https://public.tableau.com/s/gallery/beatles-analysis

https://public.tableau.com/s/gallery/american-whiskey-wheel

I am trying to create the same effect on my own data set. I am not sure how Adam was able to line up the sankey portion with the bar chart perfectly. I have tried many different ID2 field configurations and varying metric fields in the `Curve` calculated field options with no success. I haven't been able to get them to line up exactly. I would also like my bases to start in different locations along the sankey and not all originating from the left.

I realize that the examples are working with much smaller data sets but believe that this should still be possible with my data. I have tried `Business ID` in my curve formula and wondering if I need to have a more generic metric in my model. Andy uses `Song ID` which is a number between 1 and 45. My IDs range from 3-3000. You can see in the workbook attached how I am setting up these fields to get the curve of the Sankey. Is it possible to get them to line up with the barchart at the top of Dashboard 2?

UPDATE 3/22/16:
I was able to get the lines much closer to their bars by modifying the Curve-LoyaltyID2 field. I loaded it to Public for easier viewing. Some lines are still not aligning directly to their corresponding bars though.

[Tableau Public](https://public.tableau.com/views/20160322Sankey-SO2/Dashboard2?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&:showTabs=y)

Thanks for any ideas you have!